# All IB outlets seems to have disconnected and app crashes (Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, ibaction

So I'm having a problem with one of my Xcode projects: It seems like all my IB outlets have disconnected (all I see is the empty circle without the dot in the middle next to the line of code, please see the picture).

[empty / hollow circles indicating IB outlets aren't connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocNh7.png)

All the IB actions seems to be working regardless, with the exception of one. When I try to tap it, my app crashes and I receive the following error message:

"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Also the error seems to be located in the AppDelegate file: 
[Error message in AppDelegate.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPBjW.png)

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? It has been a while (a few weeks) since I last worked on this project, if that's at all relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the unfilled circles; they are not causing a problem.

The crash when you tap is not because of an IBOutlet. It is because that object's IBAction (not shown in your screen shot). That is what you need to work on.

Answer (score 0):

First check all Objects IBAction and IBOutlet or reconnect them. Sometime unfilled circles misguide you.

For better compilation you should have an exception handler in the app. Try below link:

> https://www.raywenderlich.com/152276/intermediate-debugging-xcode-8

This will help you to find exact place where you are getting issue.

hope this helps.